# Issue with filtering query between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I've got a query that as soon as I bring date results back it throws of the results a bit. This is currently for SQL Server, though I think the query should be fairly universal and it will need to be as we are migrating to a different database soon.

This is the base of the query.

```
SELECT LASTORDER
FROM IMPORTUTILITY.DBO.CUSTOMERS
WHERE ORDERCOUNT = 1
```

This is the results it returns:

[image: Example Output of query]

I've got a column `LASTORDER` which is a datetime. I try and expand the query to (FYI DD/MM/YYYY):

```
SELECT LASTORDER
FROM IMPORTUTILITY.DBO.CUSTOMERS
WHERE ORDERCOUNT = 1
  AND LASTORDER < 24/02/2023
  AND LASTORDER > 02/02/2023
```

Even if I just do `AND LASTORDER < 24/02/2023` the returned results is empty. Based on the screenshot, all those dates should be less that yesterdays date.

For what it is worth, I've tried changing the date format and that didn't seem to do much and I swear I've done similar queries to this with other databases and it's been fine. For what it is worth, those dates are populated by parameter from a different program, this is a copy of the SQL it produces.

I did try the 'between' command, however I get the same result. I'm fairly sure this is something obvious and having not used SQL for a while some brain rot has occurred.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `24/02/2023` is not a date, it's a numerical expression containing 3 `int` values and 2 divisors; 24 / 02 = 12 -> 12 / 2023 = 0. Use an **unambiguous** date formatted (`yyyyMMdd`) literal string: `'20230224'`.

Comment: That hurts me! It makes sense though. Thank you very much <3

Comment: The documentation specifies that the default date literal format is the *International* Standard ISO8601 (`'YYYY-MM-DD'`); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
SELECT LASTORDER 
FROM IMPORTUTILITY.DBO.CUSTOMERS 
WHERE ORDERCOUNT = 1 
AND LASTORDER > '2023-02-02' 
AND LASTORDER < '2023-02-24'
```

Comment: So wrapping the date and changing '/' to '-' also seems to make a difference. Guess I will need to change my date formatting at list on the query side. Thank you.